# How to edit windows workgroup or share file with gvim

Tags: vim

i have some problems when i am working with gvim in windows,i want to edit code in the

workgroup server,i want to edit files by gvim

i use :e \test\test\test.php in gvim

but this usage is not very useful,i don't know how to edit the workgroup or share file (the file is at linux server)

do you have the same ?

lots of thanks: )

Answer (score 4):

If it's shared using [CIFS or SMB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block), Just use the [UNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention) path.

```
:e //SERVER/Share/path/to/file.ext
```

Else use SSH and the the [NETRW](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html#pi_netrw.txt) plug-in that has been included with Vim installations for a while now to open the file or directory:

```
:e scp://server/path/to/file.ext
```

Comment: but how to open dir with gvim ? localhost i can open dir with :e command ,but i can't open dir //server/ dir with :e command.

Comment: @lenvens: See [`:he pi_netrw.txt`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html#pi_netrw.txt) for more information.